# How do i get the parent xml based on value of child xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an requirement like,I retrieved id and supplier from an xml which has more than 40 ID's and Suppliers.Now all i need is want to get the parent node of particular Id and Supplier and append it to another xml.

I however managed to retrieve ID and Supplier,now i want to get the whole xml in c#.Any help would be appreciable..

**c#**

```
  var action = xmlAttributeCollection["id"];
  xmlActions[i] = action.Value;
  var fileName = xmlAttributeCollection["supplier"];
  xmlFileNames[i] = fileName.Value;
```

This is the code i have used to get ID and supplier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to be a little more specific about how, you are traversing the Xml Tree, and give your variables types so we can understand the problem more clearly. In saying that here is my answer:

Assuming items[i] is an XmlNode, and in this case we are working with the "hoteId" node, there is a property called XmlNode.ParentNode which returns the immediate ancestor of a node, or null if it is a root node.

```
XmlNode currentNode = items[i] as XmlNode; //hotelId
XmlNode parentNode = currentNode.ParentNode; //hotelDetail
string outerXml = parentNode.OuterXml; //returns a string representation of the entire parent node
```

Full example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("doc.xml");

XmlNode hotelIdNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("hoteldetail//hotelId"); //Find a hotelId Node
XmlNode hotelDetailNode = hotelIdNode.ParentNode; //Get the parent node
string hotelDetailXml = hotelDetailNode.OuterXml; //Get the Xml as a string
```

Comment: id and supplier are attributes of hotelID which is the child of hoteldetail. Are you sure your code will work in this..

Comment: @Sasidharan Yes. Provided you have loaded the entire Xml structure into an XmlDocument object. You may want to provide another code snippet on how you are loading the document, and traversing the Xml tree. I'll put a full working example here for you.

Comment: basically its an xml response which is is in a string.From that string i m getting id and supplier using for loop and passing to rest sevice and in response i get another xml which is formatted using xslt and displayed in webpage

Comment: i am getting null value for  XmlNode hotelIdNode = docx.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("hoteldetail/hotelId[@id='" + action.Value + "']"); and XmlNode hotelIdNode = docx.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//hoteldetail//hotelId[@id='" + action.Value + "']");

Comment: You don't need .DocumentElement, and for some reason it does return null. This worked for me: docx.SelectSingleNode("hoteldetail//hotelId[@id='" + action.Value + "']");

Answer (score 0):

You can get Parent XML like : XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//hoteldetail"); node.innerXml;

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better off using linq.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlString);
foreach(var xElement in xDoc.Descendants("hoteldetail"))
{
    //this is your <hoteldetail>....</hoteldetail>
    var hotelDetail = xElement;
    var hotelId = hotelDetail.Element("hotelId");
    //this is your id
    var id = hotelId.Attribute("id").Value;
    //this is your supplier
    var supplier = hotelId.Attribute("supplier").Value;

    if (id == someId && supplier == someSupplier)
         return hotelDetail;
}
```

Comment: the problem is not in fetching id or supplier,i already did that..Now all i need is to get parent xml based on that id and supplier.

Comment: @Sasidharan, i added two more lines of code. I thought it was fairly obvious.